# Booting a raw disk image in QEMU

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, disk-image

I have a disk image file from [here](http://picolisp.com/wiki/?PilOS); that page says I can boot this image with QEMU and the following command:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64  -m 4096  -ctrl-grab  -no-reboot  x86-64.img
```

That gives a message:

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'x86-64.img' and probing guessed raw.
     Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
     Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

The emulator loads, but PilOS crashes, which means I did something wrong:

[image]
(probably because PilOS wants to write to block 0 but can't)

The `raw` command line argument is, as far as I can tell, meant to be passed like this:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw file=x86-64.img 
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive format=raw: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

That fails (I think) because my boot device is on `/dev/sda`, bus 0, so one of the following should work according to QEMU's man page (but doesn't):

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -drive bus=9 format=raw file=x86-64.img 
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive bus=9: Could not open 'format=raw': No such file or directory
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw file=x86-64.img bus=9
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive format=raw: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

The `bus=9` argument that `-drive` should accept is either interpreted as a filename, or completely ignored.

How do I properly boot such a raw image in QEMU?

---

This is Ubuntu 15.10, running:

```
QEMU emulator version 2.3.0 (Debian 1:2.3+dfsg-5ubuntu9.3), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Data about the image:

```
$ file x86-64.img 
x86-64.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x83, active, start-CHS (0x0,1,1), end-CHS (0x82,246,62), startsector 62, 2006072 sectors; partition 2 : ID=0x82, start-CHS (0x83,0,1), end-CHS (0x15,246,62), startsector 2006134, 2006134 sectors

$ fdisk -lu x86-64.img 
Disk x86-64.img: 670 KiB, 686080 bytes, 1340 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device      Boot   Start     End Sectors   Size Id Type
x86-64.img1 *         62 2006133 2006072 979.5M 83 Linux
x86-64.img2      2006134 4012267 2006134 979.6M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `-drive` option takes parameters that look like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=x86-64.img
```

… you need to use commas between its "sub"-options, not spaces.

For example, here is one I tested to boot a Debian Installer CD:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,media=cdrom,readonly=on,file=debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
```

Comment: how do you specify the raw option for floppy drive in the following `qemu-system-x86_64 -fda os.flp` to get rid of the warning?

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek it's in the man page—search for "Instead of -fda, -fdb, you can use:" gives `-drive file=file,index=0,if=floppy` ... so you should be able to add `format=raw` to that.

Comment: ok got it. `qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=os.flp,index=0,if=floppy` worked! Thanks.

Comment: -drive format=raw: Can't use 'raw' as a block driver for the protocol level

Comment: @Mr.Hyde considering it worked for both me and OP, that's odd! What's the full command line? Maybe it'd be best to ask a new question, you can reference this one in your question.

Comment: @derobert qemu-system-arm -m 1024M -sd armdisk.img -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9 -kernel vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-vexpress -initrd initrd.gz -append "root=/dev/ram" -no-reboot

Comment: @Mr.Hyde You don't have a `-drive` argument there, so that seems to be a different question. Suggest you ask your own question.

Comment: Working `sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive 'format=raw,file=/dev/sdX'` using file special referencing a physical storage drive.