# Boot loop device as root file system

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, grub2, root-filesystem, loop-device

I created an ext4-filesystem on a loop device with all necessary files to boot with, e.g.:

> /bin /boot /dev /lib /mnt /etc ...

Now I want to boot from the loop device as an image (let's say `filesystem.img`) with this filesystem.
Is it possible to make this loop device as the new root filesystem and to boot from it with the GRUB2 bootloader?

I also read an article about initrd to perform this with the initial ram disk: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/l-initrd/

Answer (score 0):

qemu should do the job.
I use such command to emulate booting from another hard drive:

```
sync ; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -hda /dev/sdc
```

first two sections (`sync` and `echo 3`) usually are needed single time after you have edited the image file.

`-m 1024` - sets Ram limit.

`-enable-kvm` - can be omited if causing problems.

`-hda /dev/sdc` - this part you should change..

here is a better answer - [Booting a raw disk image in QEMU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276480/booting-a-raw-disk-image-in-qemu)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case, I want to boot directly from GRUB with that disk image. Do you know if this is possible? It seems like it is not possible with QEMU, am I right?

Comment: Well, it is sure possible with GRUB

Answer (score 0):

1. load into GRUB2 and enter its command line mode (hit 'c') and investigate how it enumerated your disks in `(hdN,N)` fashion with `ls` command
2. load into GRUB2 and edit any entry (hit 'e') , edit it into something like https://superuser.com/a/1300189/702372 according to your files location . Load it by hittin Ctrl-x
3. to make a permanent entry, follow the answer from 2.

Comment: Thank you once again. I got problems booting into my filesystem. I got in my main partition `(hd0, msdos1)`, the following file is my filesystem: `filesystem.img`. My entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` is: `menuentry "test" {         insmod linux         set isofile="boot/filesystem.img"         loopback loop (hd0,msdos1)/${isofile}         linux (loop)/vmlinuz         initrd (loop)/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-187-generic }`. But after that, when I boot from it, I get an error message `attempt to read or write outside of disk 'loop'.` Do you know a solution?

Comment: I practiced it a bit. Probably I can tell you exact commands if you tell how you made that fs.img file.